# jQuery Value append and remove attribute value according to condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using append and attr method of jQuery and the input append with input value and bootstrap modal value.But somehow my code is not running according to condition my jQuery code is

```
$("input").change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#gwrmodal").modal({backdrop: "static"}); // open modal
    $("button").click(function(){
      var gwrvalue = $(this).val();
      var id= $("#appenddiv div").length;
      $("#appenddiv div").each(function() {
        var fieldWrapper =$("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + Id + "\"/>"); //apped wrapper
        var gwrtoken = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" value=\"" + value+ "\"  disabled/>"); //append token value
        var Time = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" value=\"" + gwrvalue+ "\" disabled/>");//append time value
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");//remove button
        removeButton.click(function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(gwrtoken);
        fieldWrapper.append(gwrTime);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#appenddiv").append(fieldWrapper);
      });
      var sum= 0;
      for(var i=0;i<=id;i++){
        sum +=time;// sum of the time
        return sum;
      }
      if(sum>3){ //condition if value is greater than 3
        var removeValue =$("#input input:last").removeAttr("value");
        $("#newinput").attr("value").val(removeValue);
        return sum=0; // for next input condition
      }
    });
  });
```

my jsfiddle is
https://jsfiddle.net/2snbaspw/

I want to append input value with bootstrap modal value and if sum of bootstrap modal value is greater than 3 the input value will remove and and show in next div input.

Comment: sum+=time; here time is not defined;

Comment: Always remember; console is developer's best friend; use it in plenty.

Comment: Thank you for your response, ok i will return time from previous scope but still my code is not working

Comment: Thank you @Rajkumar Somasundaram, i have updated my jsfiddle

Comment: time is still undefined

Comment: sorry, its not getting update please use this link for check https://jsfiddle.net/e47zxhq4/

Comment: time is still not defined; few more typos that i fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/2snbaspw/

;; I cant help you if you wont let me

Comment: Thank you @ Rajkumar Somasundaram, i have updated this for time https://jsfiddle.net/2snbaspw/

Comment: your missing some variables to internalize like `gwroverTime` and `time` should be like `var sum = time = 0`; then update your fiddle

Comment: @AbdulRafay thank you for your response  please check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2snbaspw/

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/2snbaspw/4/

Comment: @AbdulRafay thank you for your response, but the i want  remove last  value from first div and append in new div in first place, if sum is greater than 3

Answer (score 0):

initialize variable:

```
$("input").change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   $("#gwrmodal").modal({backdrop: "static"}); // open modal
   $("button").click(function(){
   .........
   var time = gwrvalue; --- here
   var sum= 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<=id;i++){
    sum +=time;// sum of the time
    return sum;
  }
  if(sum>3){ //condition if value is greater than 3
    // Change Here
    $("#input input:eq("+getIndex+")").val();
            $("#newinput input:eq("+getIndex+")").val(sum);
            console.log('New Value' + $("#newinput input:eq("+getIndex+")").attr('type'))
            sum = 0; // for next input condition
  }
  });
});
```

check this latest code:
https://jsfiddle.net/2snbaspw/5/

Comment: Thank you for answer , but the value should be show in new div (class="newinput") only if the sum of gwrvalue value is greater than 3, and it should be remove from originate(id="input") div

Comment: and the div  (id="appenddiv") is append more than 1 append if i input second time or input second value

Comment: sum should not be input value, but sum be selected value from bootstrap modal and this has 3 option 1,2 and 3, and after input change the modal is appearing